# Removing a specific string out of an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Good day, I'm trying to achieve the task of removing a specific string in an ArrayList, which I think has been converted to an defaultlist? 
However, I've come across several difficulties doing so, and I would like to know what I'm doing incorrectly. 
This is being done in JavaSwing, I'll provide the method which I believe deletes it, I do believe that my problem is that I don't update the list.

I shall provide with my main jFrame: Let me know if you want any other classes, they're quite long.

```
package is.hi.torg.vidmot;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package is.hi.torg.vidmot;

import is.hi.torg.gogn.LagaListi;
import is.hi.torg.styring.StyringListi;
import is.hi.torg.vinnsla.FlokkarModel;
import is.hi.torg.vinnsla.LagaListiModel;
import is.hi.torg.vinnsla.TonlistarKatalogur;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Ebba Þóra Hvannberg ebba@hi.is
 */
public class AdalTorg extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final TonlistarKatalogur minnKatalogur;
    public AdgerdTag getAdgerd() {
        return adgerd;
    }

    /**
     * @param adgerd the adgerd to set
     */
    public void setAdgerd(AdgerdTag adgerd) {
        this.adgerd = adgerd;
    }

    public enum AdgerdTag {SKODA, EYDA, BREYTA};

    private AdgerdTag adgerd=AdgerdTag.SKODA;




    LagaListi minnLagaListi;
    /**
     * Creates new form AdalTorg
     */
    public AdalTorg() {
             initComponents();

        // Lesum inn XML gögn með því að smíða TónlistarKatalog
              minnKatalogur = new TonlistarKatalogur();


        // Birtum  lögin 

             minnKatalogur.birtaLogin();

              birtaLag(3);
        List.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new StyringListi(this));
              FlokkarModel fModel = new FlokkarModel(minnKatalogur.getFlokkar());
              jFlokkar.setModel(fModel.getModel());


              LagaListiModel list = new LagaListiModel(minnKatalogur.getLagaListi());
              List.setModel(list); 



    }

    public TonlistarKatalogur getTonlistarKatalog(){

        return minnKatalogur; 
    }
    private void printO(int i){
        jTextArea1.append("Flytjandi: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getFlytjandi() + "\n" + 
                      "Lag: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getTitill() + "\n" + 
                      "Höfundur: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getHofundur() + "\n" + 
                      "Flokkur :" + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getFlokkur().getHeiti() + "\n" +
                      "Undirflokkur: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getUndirflokkur().getHeiti() + "\n\n");
    }

    private void birtaLag(int indexLag) {


        System.out.println ("lag nr. "+(indexLag+1));
        System.out.println (
                minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(indexLag).getTitill());

         System.out.println (
        minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(indexLag).getFlytjandi());

        System.out.println (
        minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(indexLag).getFlokkur().getHeiti());

        System.out.println (
        minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(indexLag).getUndirflokkur().getHeiti());

           jTextArea1.setText("XML skrá komin!"); 
    }   

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jFlokkar = new javax.swing.JTree();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        List = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        Delete_Me = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jFlokkar);

        List.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        List.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ListMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(List);

        jButton1.setText("Ok ");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        Delete_Me.setText("Delete me");
        Delete_Me.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Delete_MeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(Delete_Me)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 186, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 267, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addComponent(jScrollPane3)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(Delete_Me)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
jTextArea1.setText(""); 
jButton1.setVisible(false); 
    }                                        

    private void ListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        dialog dlg = new dialog(this,true); 



                 //NamskeidDialog namskeidDialog = new NamskeidDialog (this, true);

    }                                 

    private void Delete_MeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        setAdgerd(AdgerdTag.EYDA);


    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdalTorg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdalTorg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdalTorg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AdalTorg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AdalTorg().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }``
```

//AdalTorg is the main JFrame, The only thing I want to know is what I'm doing wrong, I'm pretty positive I'm not updating the list after I remove something out of it, if so, where is my error and where do I fix it?

```
package is.hi.torg.styring;

import is.hi.torg.gogn.LagaListi;
import is.hi.torg.vidmot.AdalTorg;
import is.hi.torg.vidmot.dialog;
import is.hi.torg.vidmot.AdalTorg.AdgerdTag;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;




/**
    *
 * @author Lenovo
 */
public class StyringListi implements ListSelectionListener{

private AdalTorg TorgAdal;
public StyringListi(AdalTorg Torg){

TorgAdal = Torg; 


}
@Override
 public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent evt) {
       ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)evt.getSource();


       AdgerdTag a = TorgAdal.getAdgerd();
       int index = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();  
       switch(a){
           case SKODA: 
               Printo(index); 
               break;


                 case BREYTA:

               break; 
           case EYDA:
               EydO(index); 





       }
            TorgAdal.setAdgerd(AdgerdTag.SKODA);
 }




 private void Printo(int i){

     dialog Dialog = new dialog(TorgAdal,true); 
      Dialog.TextO.append("Flytjandi:"+ TorgAdal.getTonlistarKatalog().getLagaListi().get(i).getFlytjandi()+"\n"+
                          "Lag: " + TorgAdal.getTonlistarKatalog().getLagaListi().get(i).getTitill() + "\n" + 
                          "Höfundur: " + TorgAdal.getTonlistarKatalog().getLagaListi().get(i).getHofundur() + "\n" +
                          "Flokkur :" + TorgAdal.getTonlistarKatalog().getLagaListi().get(i).getFlokkur().getHeiti() + "\n" +
                          "Undirflokkur: " + TorgAdal.getTonlistarKatalog().getLagaListi().get(i).getUndirflokkur().getHeiti() + "\n\n");

     Dialog.setVisible(true); 
      //"Flytjandi: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getFlytjandi() + "\n" + 
            //          "Lag: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getTitill() + "\n" + 
             //         "Höfundur: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getHofundur() + "\n" + 
              //        "Flokkur :" + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getFlokkur().getHeiti() + "\n" +
                //      "Undirflokkur: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getUndirflokkur().getHeiti() + "\n\n");


 }
  private void EydO(int i){

          if (i == -1)
              return;
          String s = TorgAdal.getTonlistarKatalog().getLagaListi().get(i).getTitill();
           if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TorgAdal, "Viltu eyða námskeiðinu? "+s, "Laginu", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==0)

                TorgAdal.getTonlistarKatalog().eydaLagi(i);



 }


}
```

// This is the function which steers the List, I think.

Edit, this function is suppose to make the DefaultArrayList.

```
package is.hi.torg.vinnsla;

import is.hi.torg.gogn.LagaListi;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Lenovo
 */
public class LagaListiModel extends DefaultListModel {

    public LagaListiModel( ArrayList<LagaListi.Lag> lagaListi){



        for(int i = 0; i <lagaListi.size();i++)
        {
        String s = lagaListi.get(i).getTitill();
        this.addElement(s);

        }

    }




}
And here I call on all the functions, am I doing it incorrectly?


public AdalTorg() {
                 initComponents();

            // Lesum inn XML gögn með því að smíða TónlistarKatalog
                  minnKatalogur = new TonlistarKatalogur();


            // Let's show some songs

                 minnKatalogur.birtaLogin();

                  birtaLag(3);
            List.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new StyringListi(this));
                  FlokkarModel fModel = new FlokkarModel(minnKatalogur.getFlokkar());
                  jFlokkar.setModel(fModel.getModel());


                  LagaListiModel list = new LagaListiModel(minnKatalogur.getLagaListi());
                  List.setModel(list); 



        }




   public TonlistarKatalogur getTonlistarKatalog(){

        return minnKatalogur; 
    }
    private void printO(int i){
        jTextArea1.append("Flytjandi: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getFlytjandi() + "\n" + 
                      "Lag: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getTitill() + "\n" + 
                      "Höfundur: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getHofundur() + "\n" + 
                      "Flokkur :" + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getFlokkur().getHeiti() + "\n" +
                      "Undirflokkur: " + minnKatalogur.getLagaListi().get(i).getUndirflokkur().getHeiti() + "\n\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.
2. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character.
3. Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character.
4. Class names SHOULD be descriptive. "dialog" is not descriptive and does not start with an upper case.

> I'm trying to achieve the task of removing a specific string in an ArrayList, which I think has been converted to an defaultlist?

I don't even see where you use an ArrayList in the code.

> This is the function which steers the List, I think.

Well if you don't know how do you expect us to know?

> List.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel()

You are using an AbstractListModel which does not support a remove() method. Use the DefaultListModel.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` examples shows you how to dynamically add and remove items from the list.

Download the demo code and play with it and then modify your code.

Comment: Oh! My apologies, I'll put some more code in my question. Thanks for replying me.